# Deepcopy in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In reducers,we always use `Object.assign({},state,newState)` to save a state. But `assign()` doesn't support deepcopy,because this method only copy a reference of multi-level object. This is my code in program.

```js
const menuListState={
 menuList: {},
 menuListLoading:false
}
function getMenuList(state=menuListState,action=defaultAction){
 switch(action.type){
  //menuList begin
  case actions.GET_MENULIST_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({},state,{
       menuList:action.data,
       menuListLoading:false
      });

  default:
   return state;
 }
}
```

The property `menuList` is a multi-level Object. And when `action.data` changes, will `state.menuList` be changed immediately before the method `assign()` work?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify` to stringify an object, and use `JSON.parse` to parse your result string into an object, you will get your new object same with the one you want to deeply copy.

Example:

```
let copiedObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalObject))
```

Comment: I've heard that this is actually really fast because it is implemented natively

Comment: Whilst the answer is not some native React process, this process has been the accepted answer for similar things like Angular JS 1 for a long time (due to performance and brevity). Upvoted

Comment: Watch out for issues with dates roundtripping with this method.

Comment: Also, watch out for regex, they get replaced by empty strings

Comment: Yes, and so does the type of js function.

Comment: This only works if your object does not contain: `Dates, functions, undefined, Infinity, RegExps, Maps, Sets, Blobs, FileLists, ImageDatas, sparse Arrays, Typed Arrays or other complex types` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/5815054. Else use somehing linke `lodash.clonedeep`, see other answers.

Answer (score 13):

You may be interested in [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep) form lodash, used as follows:

```
var objects = [{ 'a': 1 }, { 'b': 2 }];

var deep = _.cloneDeep(objects);
console.log(deep[0] === objects[0]);
// => false
```

[Heres the npm package for just that method.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep)

Answer (score 1):

You can do, JSON serialisation,

```
var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObjCopy));
```

but, its not recommended as,
you may lose any Javascript, JSON property like `Function` or `undefined`.Those get ignored by `JSON.stringify`, causing them to be missed on the cloned object.
`Date` object results into `string`.
instead you can use easiest `Lodash`,

```
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';
var clone = cloneDeep(oldObjCopy);
```

Answer (score 1):

Very interested this thread. HERE is my rough profiling in chrome. largeObj is about 15k chars

```
let i, t = new Date().getTime();
for(i=0;i<1000;i++) cloneDeep(largeObj)
console.log('clone', new Date().getTime() - t);

t = new Date().getTime();
for(i=0;i<1000;i++) JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(largeObj));
console.log('JSON', new Date().getTime() - t);
```

And the below is my result. "clone" won

```
clone 46
JSON 82
clone 42
JSON 87
clone 45
JSON 87
clone 46
JSON 85
clone 44
JSON 86
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure if `action.data` is reference types (object, array,...), `state.menuList` will be changed immediately when you change `action.data` because they reference to the same value. It's just a normal functional of Javascript.